# modify the echo service of Suse enterprise Linux

Tags: echo, suse

I need to make a small change of the echo service in Suse enterprise server 10 sp1. I has some questions:
  Where can I download the source code?
  Is there a brief guide to build it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the `echo` service is implemented in the `xinetd` tool directly. Look for an `xinetd*src.rpm` on your install media and either use `cpan2rpm` to unpack the RPM or `rpm -i` to unpack the rpm into your configured `RPMBUILD` directory. There are some details on using source rpm packages here: http://linuxmafia.com/pub/linux/suse-linux-internals/chapter34.html